# asp.net mvc 5 pagination in my guestbook view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I'm just learning MVC 5 and i want to create a paging after 10 comments have been posted on the page. The code is very simple so far.

Here is my Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var Inlägg = db.Gästbok.OrderByDescending(Gästbok => Gästbok.Datum).Take(10).ToList();

        return View(Inlägg);
    }
```

Here is the View:

```
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Kommentar)</p>
            <br />

            <p>Postad: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Datum) Av: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Namn) (@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email))</p>

            <hr />
        }

        <button class="btn btn-default">
            @Html.ActionLink("Skriv nytt inlägg", "Create")
        </button>
```

So if anyone can give me a simple example or explanation to how i can implement a pagination here I would really appriciate it! Thanks in advance!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend installing the [`PagedList.MVC`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList/):

```
Install-Package PagedList
```

Then implement something like this:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, int pageSize = 10)
{
    var inlägg = db.Gästbok.OrderByDescending(g => g.Datum).ToList();
    var model = new PagedList<Gästbok>(inlägg, page, pageSize);

    return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model PagedList<Gästbok>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Kommentar)</p>
    <br />

    <p>
        Postad: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Datum) 
        Av: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Namn
        (@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email))
    </p>

    <hr />
}

<p>
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
        new { page, pageSize = Model.PageSize }))

    Showing @Model.FirstItemOnPage to @Model.LastItemOnPage
        of @Model.TotalItemCount comments.
</p>
<hr />

<button class="btn btn-default">
    @Html.ActionLink("Skriv nytt inlägg", "Create")
</button>
```

And add the `PagedList` dlls to the `<namespaces>` element in the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` section under `<configuration>` in the `Views/Web.config` as follows:

```
<configuration>
  (...)
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    (...)
    <namespaces>
      (...)
      <add namespace="PagedList" />
      <add namespace="PagedList.Mvc" />
    </namespaces>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

It will look something like this:

[image: Picture from own site]

Comment: Sorry about a really late response... I'm getting an error with the @model at the top of the View page. Type or Namespace could not be found

Comment: No problem. You have to add the namespaces to Razor's `namespaces` element in the `Views/Web.Config`. See my update to the answer.

Comment: Oh yeah! I was thinking I had to do something in the Web.config file. Thank you!! its working great now!